# Finding document in mongodb collection where key matches particular value in list of documents

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I'm new to MongoDB and I'm trying to query the following collection (named **sample**):

```
{
    "_id": "thresholds",
    "thresholds": [{
        "GRADE": "CC004",
        "C": "",
        "CF": "",
        "MN": "0.01",
        "N": "",
        "P": "0.03",
        "SI": "",
        "CR": ""
    }, {
        "GRADE": "CC005",
        "C": "",
        "CF": "",
        "MN": "",
        "N": "",
        "P": "",
        "SI": "",
        "CR": ""
    }]
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the entire record where the "GRADE" is "CC004".

Right now, I'm doing the following: `db.sample.find({"thresholds": {"GRADE": "CC004"}})`. However, it's returning null value because nothing was found. How can I rephrase my query to find my entry of interest?

Comment: This is Python @MohamedMoselhy

Comment: Is this Python 3 or Python 4?

Comment: a7a @MohamedMoselhy

Comment: In that case, have you tried the using "distinct" instead of "find"? For example: db.sample.distinct("thresholds", {'GRADE': 'CC005'})

Comment: Yes, no matches found

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 0):

You could make the following query:

```js
db.sample.find({"thresholds.GRADE": "CC004"})
```

Comment: Hi @Neslon, thanks for your reply. I tried this and it retrieved the ALL the documents in the list not that particular one I'm interested in.

Comment: Please only post answers in English. Thanks.